# How to measure DC voltage without knowing which pin is ground

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I have a connector from the motor controller to the display on my e-bike that has five pins in it. The system is powered by a 52V battery.

I would like to find out which pin carries the battery voltage, and which one is the ground. The three other pins are much lower voltage, sending 52V to them would cause damage.

My issue is that I don't know how to safely make the measurements with a voltmeter without risking shorting the 52V pin with one that wasn't the ground. Can I just hook up my voltmeter's black probe to the (metal) frame of the bicycle and safely measure the pins in the connector one by one?

Comment: voltage measurement procedure does not short pins

Comment: what is preventing you from using the battery negative terminal as ground reference?

Comment: The battery and it's connectors are well encased to avoid accidental shorts, I can't access the battery terminals while it's connected unless I splice the cable (not an option)

Comment: I'd be pretty surprised if the voltage you measure going to the display is 52V.

Comment: It is, that's how the display shows the remaining battery capacity.

Comment: Re, "that's how the display shows the remaining battery capacity." Do you know that for a fact? Five conductors is not very many. It's _possible_ that one of them is dedicated to sensing the battery voltage, but it would make a lot more sense if the value that you see shown on the battery gauge was transmitted as a digital signal from the motor control unit to the display head.

Comment: Others have probed their pins, and there is a pin that carries full battery voltage to the display. When the display is off the battery and powered by an external power supply directly without the motor/controller in the way (it takes 27V minimum, up to 60), the display works and shows whatever power is supplied as the battery voltage. The reason I want to probe my pins is that there are different wiring for the same connector... As long as the display and motor are matched you're fine, but that's not always the case with replacement displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to find out which pin carries the battery voltage, and which one is the ground. The three other pins are much lower voltage, sending 52V to them would cause damage.

Modern digital multimeters typically have an input impedance of 10 MΩ. They are so sensitive that they can for many practical applications - such as your battery measurement - be considered ideal in that they pass no current while measuring the voltage. This means that the points being measured stay at their own voltage and are not shorted or pulled to the higher voltage while making that measurement.

- Switch to DC volts and plug the leads into the correct sockets.
- Connect the black lead to pin 1 and probe the others with the red lead. Record your measurements.
- The pin with the lowest reading is most likely to be the battery negative.
- The pin with the highest reading is likely to be the battery positive.
- Subtract the lowest from the highest (do it properly if the low reading is negative) and the difference should be the battery voltage.

Comment: _"Connect the black lead to pin 1 and probe the others with the red lead... The pin with the lowest reading is most likely to be the battery negative."_ - unless pin 1 is battery negative...

Comment: Thank you. It did work that way, and didn't damage anything. I just made sure to have the black probe on COM on the multimeter, and the red one on V/mA. I was also able to confirm which is B+ and GND by disconnecting the battery and checking for continuity between the red wire normally connecting the motor to the battery and the pin I though was B+, and doing the same for GND. It's the right ones when there is continuity/0 ohms resistance.